# How to call class methods which are stored in a variable

Tags: ruby, class-method

If I want to call a class method (mailer method in rails), providing its name in a variable. How can I do that? For objects, we can use `send`, or we can use `read_attribute` to read some values

```
my_object.send("#{self.action_type(self)}")
my_object.read_attribute("#{self.action_type}_email")
```

But for class names, nothing is working as `send` is defined as instance method in object class. I want something like this, which will not work as `send` can't be applied on class:

```
Notifier.send("#{self.action_type(self)}").deliver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are objects. There is no difference in how you apply `send`.

```
Notifier.send(action_type, self).deliver
```

Comment: Perfect.. :) Worked like charm

Comment: Doesn't this render this question completely worthless? Why did you say in your question that send didn't work on the Class? :/

Comment: @MikeCampbell You don't need to blame the OP for the mistake. Coming to know that classes are objects, and therefore that `send` indeed works on them is a good achievement.

Comment: I'm not "blaming" the OP, I'm just questioning the value of a question where the accepted answer contradicts the premise of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `eval`

```
eval("Notifier.#{self.action_type}(self).deliver")
```

Not safe but it should work.

Comment: Answers needs a minor fix and then it worked.. Made that modification in answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
method = Notifier.method(action_type)
method.call(self).deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

`self.class.send(:your_class_method)`